# ASP.NET HttpModule fails with NullReference exception when trying to Access Request.Url

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, nullreferenceexception, httpcontext, httpmodule

I have an `HttpModule` to process some custom logic with every `HttpRequest` and for some reason in rare cases it throws a `NullReferenceException` error when I'm trying to access `HttpRequest.Url`.

Before accessing the `Url` I'm checking if `HttpContext` is there and `Request` object is not null. Here is the stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] 
    System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetQueryStringRawBytes() +55 
    System.Web.HttpRequest.get_QueryStringText() +76 
    System.Web.HttpRequest.BuildUrl(Func`1 pathAccessor) +42 
    System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Url() +88 
    MyHttpModule.BeginRequestEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) at +xx      
    System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +175 
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +168
```

I've also checked the .NET source for additional information and wasn't able to locate a place for NullReference:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/IIS7WorkerRequest.cs,68b1222d24e7bd28

Here is the code:

```
public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += this.BeginRequestEventHandler;
    }

    private void BeginRequestEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpContext = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        if (httpContext == null || httpContext.Request == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var url = httpContext.Request.Url;
        // process url
    }
}
```

This happens in rare cases but looks critical as long as it happens during processing regular http requests.

Comment: Can you show the code in question as a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated my question to include MCV example

Comment: Does the error happen on that last line or when accessing the variable? Stack trace seems to indicate that the error happens when trying to access the query string of the URL. Could be that the incoming request does not have a query string and the code tries to access it.

Comment: Error occurs when the code is trying to access Url property (get_Url from the stacktrace). Incoming request can totally have no query string, there plenty of requests to various of resources. As I can see from the stacktrace the error occurs inside the .NET Framework `IIS7WorkerRequest.GetQueryStringRawBytes` method

Comment: Do you have any examples of the full Url and querystrings that cause these errors? Is there any pattern or commonality to them? These could be malicious requests specifically designed to cause errors.

Comment: I do have those request, they are regular requests, the pattern is that those requests are being done right after a deployment or even during the deployment

Comment: Which .NET version you're on? Is it 4.6.2?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try getting `HttpContext` from `HttpContext.Current`?

```
public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += this.BeginRequestEventHandler;
    }

    private void BeginRequestEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryStringText doesn't work as well, same issue

Comment: Request doesn't have `QueryStringText` property; you need to use ***QueryString***. For example, `string name = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"];`.

Comment: I'm using the public `HttpRequest.get_Url() +88` property while it internally trying to build the url via `get_QueryStringText() +76` -> `BuildUrl(Func`1 pathAccessor) +42` and fails

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from the stack trace, the code fails when .NET framework tries to extract the Query-string from the context. Looking at the code, it seems the exception is thrown by `unsafe` code, which means some pointer is set to zero somewhere.

I would assume there's a bug in IIS, that is triggered when it processes malformed requests, such as query-strings with a null-character encoded into it, or something like that.

Make sure you install all IIS hotfixes https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19863.list-of-iis-7-5-related-hotfixes-post-sp1-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1.aspx

Also, you can try going with `Request.Path` or `Request.FilePath` instead of URL, or imply add a `try-catch` and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this, it should have no problems:

```
if (httpContext.Request != null)
{
    if (httpContext.Request.Url != null)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.Url;
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like `Url` can be null moreover the stack trace points deeper to the .net code which means it'll throw a NullReff during executing the line `httpContext.Request.Url != null`